# jQuery: find closest element that is not necessarily a parent

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I am well aware of the `closest()` function that "Travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied selector". However, is there a way to have this function search all elements and their children from the point defined?

```
<ul id="one" class="level-1">
  <li class="item-i">I</li>
  <li id="ii" class="item-ii">II
  <ul class="level-2">
    <li class="item-a">A</li>
    <li class="item-b">B
      <ul class="level-3">
        <li class="item-1">1</li>
        <li class="item-2">2</li>
        <li class="item-3">3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item-c">C</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item-iii">III</li>
</ul>
```

If I select an element with a class of `item-iii` and want to return the element that has a class of `item-3`, what would the selector look like? If I understand `closest()` correctly, it will go up the DOM tree but never check if any of the elements have a child that matches the second selector.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're looking for.  Are you trying to do something like "find the element with class `item-3` that is somewhere inside the same `ul` that I am in? If so, I'd use `parent` to go as high as you want to go, and then use `find`.

Comment: @JacobM i think the same but instead using: `$(this).closest('ul').find('.item-3')`

Comment: Could you not just search from the top and use `find()`? `$("body").find(".item-3");`

Comment: Ciaran: that's the equivalent of just doing `$('.item-3')`.

Comment: A. Wolff: that will behave a bit differently because what if the initial element that he selected happens to be inside a ul that isn't the top level one? I was picturing using `parent` to go high enough to guarantee that you're at the level you want, and then `find`.

Comment: @JacobM ya sure, but you can use different selector as `$(this).closest('.level-1').find('.item-3')`, etc... I don't know what exactly OP expects

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Searching all the parents for `.item-3` elements, then getting the first (closest) of those, and then finding the actualy `.item-3` elements in the closest parent that has such an element, will be ineffecient, but can be done like so:

```
$(this).parents(':has(.item-3)').first().find('.item-3');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6nHZC/)

if it's just within the sibling LI's it could be more efficient

```
$(this).siblings(':has(.item-3)').first().find('.item-3');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6nHZC/1/)

etc, the more specific, generelly the more efficient.

it would even work with `closest();`

```
$(this).closest(':has(.item-3)').find('.item-3');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6nHZC/2/)

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Didn't think of using `find()` for the closest elements. Third option works best. Thank you!

Comment: One more question, is there a way to limit this to search for elements that are above the one specified (in your case `$this`)?

Comment: Yes, you can do `$(this).parent().closest(':has(.item-3)').find('.item-3');` as closest() starts with the current element, and that would make it start with the parent element instead.

Comment: As a sidenote, I would generally avoid using `parents()` (with an **s**) as it's terribly ineffecient.

Comment: But `parent()` only returns the immediate parent, what about if it's the third parent above that somewhere as its child contains the desired class?